# "Points to Consider" before releasing a .NET Product Beta

Tags: release, beta, product

I am planning to release a .NET product as Beta in the next couple of weeks. I want to know what points should be considered before releasing a product. I think the following needs to be taken care of:

1. Professional Icons/Splash and About screens
2. Obfuscation of assemblies
3. Sign the assemblies - Strong Name
4. Professional Security Certificate (Verisign/Thwate) - Authenticode signing assemblies
5. Google AdWords, AdSense and Analytics
6. Writing blogs etc about the application features
7. A way to get bug/features from BETA users

Basically the question is how to release an effective BETA and make my product popular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Obfuscation of assemblies

Only if obfuscation does not decrease the quality and usefulness of (automatic) bug and crash reports.

> Professional Security Certificate (Verisign/Thwate) - Authenticode signing assemblies

I don't think this is an important point for a BETA. If you can afford it, its a plus. However, it won't make your application more popular. Also, you won't loose potential users if you miss a certificate - whoever downloads and installs your application will not abort just because your stuff is not signed.

But there's another point missing: you need a fancy website. 'fancy' means: it must look professional, fit to your product and lead straight to a download link. The product needs to be easily installable - really easy. Small download size is also a plus in my opinion.

> Writing blogs etc about the application features

Increases your google ranking, but needs to be used with care. If you fill hundreds of blogs, everybody will know it's YOU advertising your product. Nobody likes self-advertising. Let your users spread the word for your. A good application in a market niche won't need much advertising ...

> Professional Icons/Splash and About screens

Is a good point to make the application look more polished, but the effect on potential users needn't be positive: nobody likes BETAs with awesome splashscreens and icons if they crash all the time.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments. I think "Professional Security Certificate (Verisign/Thwate) - Authenticode signing assemblies" will certainly make a positive impact on the users as they will have a sense of security if the application is certified by these authorities.
For a new company, I think this point can really make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

The question

> how to release an effective BETA and make my product popular?

has little to do with all the points you stated.

It is 95% marketing thing than technical.

But I would consider the most important ones for Betas:

1. Easy way to submit bug-reports/feature request (2 clicks, no more; 1 minute of user's time).
2. Usability.
3. Product demos to get started easily.

The first is crucial as it will give you the first feedback on the application.

Comment: I want to get developer views on releasing a BETA. There are no marketing people involved in my projects and I am the team here.